# Please review my game in the King's Gambit Accepted

Tags: analysis, kings-gambit

In the following game I played as White where I was mated. Can you comment on my game and how to improve?

I'm particularly interested in understanding the my opponent's mating attack.

```
[FEN ""]
[Event "Live Chess"]
[Site "Chess.com"]
[Date "2016.05.26"]
[White "anandsadasivam"]
[Black "PMajstor"]
[Result "0-1"]
[WhiteElo "878"]
[BlackElo "886"]
[TimeControl "10|0"]
[Termination "PMajstor won by checkmate"]

1.e4 e5 2.f4 exf4 3.Qg4 Bd6 4.d4 f6 5.c4 Nh6 6.Qf3 b6 7.a4 a5 8.h4 O-O 9.Bxf4 Bxf4 10.Qxf4 d6
 11.g4 Nxg4 12.Ne2 h6 13.Bh3 f5 14.Rf1 Qxh4+ 15.Ng3 Qxh3 16.Nxf5 Bxf5 17.exf5 Ne3 18.b3 Nc2+ 19.Kd1 Nxa1 20.Kc1 Rxf5
 21.Qxf5 Nxb3+ 22.Kd1 Qxf5 23.Rxf5 Nxd4 24.Rf4 Nbc6 25.Nc3 Rf8 26.Re4 Nf3 27.Nd5 Ng5 28.Rg4 Rf1+ 29.Ke2 Rf8 30.Nxc7 Ne5
 31.Rd4 Rd8 32.Nd5 Nc6 33.Rf4 Re8+ 34.Kd3 Ne5+ 35.Kc3 Ng6 36.Rf1 Ne4+ 37.Kd4 Nd2 38.Rd1 Nf3+ 39.Kc3 Nge5 40.Nxb6 Rb8
 41.Rxd6 Ng5 42.Nd7 Ne4+ 43.Kd4 Nxd6 44.Nxb8 Nexc4 45.Nc6 g5 46.Kd3 g4 47.Ke2 g3 48.Kf1 h5 49.Kg2 h4 50.Kh3 Nf5
 51.Nd8 Nb2 52.Nc6 Nc4 53.Nd8 Kf8 54.Ne6+ Ke7 55.Ng7 Nxg7 56.Kxh4 g2 57.Kh3 g1=Q 58.Kh4 Ne6 59.Kh5 Kf6 60.Kh6 Qh1#
 0-1
```

Comment: Why didn't you grab his pawn with 4.Qxg7 or 5.Qxg7 or 6.Qxg7?

Comment: I had to stop after white's 11th. Too many pawns moves. You violate basic opening principles too casually. I think you need to read a basic chess book or some basic beginner level chess videos on Chess.com. You are the target audience.

Comment: As pointed out, the game violates many basic principles. While the main problem was hanging pieces, I encourage you to learn those principles (develop pieces, castle, control the center, connect the rooks, etc.) with videos or books.

Answer (score 8):

I think your first step toward improvement has to be: don't just lose material. 11.g4 is the first example I see. There seems no rhyme nor reason for just letting the opponent have that pawn. Next is 14.Rf1. There seem to be reasonable ways to not lose the h4 pawn. And finally 15.Ng3 dropping a whole piece on h3, when 15.Bg2 would have saved it. Why keep material? 1) More material for you means you have more material to launch attacks, and 2) More material also gives you more defenses for your king if your opponent goes on a premature king attack.

Answer (score 2):

The main sense of playing a gambit is to sacrifice material in order to have some kind of compensation. In the KGA, you give black a pawn for quick development and central control. For this reason 3. Qg4 don't make a lot of sense. Your queen can easily be harassed by black pieces (for example 3... Nf6 or 3... d5 black will give you back the pawn and have a better development).

After 2... exf4 you have three reasonable choices 3. Nf3 3.Bc4 or 3. Nc3 (I have no experience in this one but it is know as Keres gambit and to me it looks more risky than the other two options). You can look to some Morphy, Bronstein or Spassky games to have an idea of the main themes of this opening. Of course it is better to improve the rest of your gameplay first...

Answer (score 0):

Dev Anand Sadasivam

In my analysis will start after 6..Nh6
How I would proceed after that move, I would play: `6. Qxg7` smash black's kingside and get his pieces tangled up. And a continuation could be this 
`6.... Nf7 7. Nc3 c6 8. Qg4 c5 9. dxc5 Bxc5 10. Nd5 Nc6 11. Qxf4 Qa5+ 12. Bd2 Qd8 13. Nxf6+ Kf8` White is up two pawns and needs to castle queen side.  
As well I agree with Jeff Y with not dropping pieces.